# Apache Camel logging with i18 and translation placeholder

Tags: logging, apache-camel

I have a Camel application and trying to implement logging for "en" and "de" languages based on the selected language.
Translation keys are in the format:
EN file:
myappname.mymodule.translation = Message with id {0} has been processed
DE file:
myappname.mymodule.translation = Nachricht mit id {0} wurde bearbeitet

I cannot find a way to pass both a key and a property to ".log" route.

Can anyone exmplain me is this possible and if so how? I researched possible everything there is but could find a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Log EIP in Apache Camel does not support i18n logging.

Comment: Thank you. Is there any other way to impement i18?

Comment: My only idea is to intercept .log